# Display the courses whose value is not 0.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this python script using class where it gets the student name, student number, student course and its grades.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.courses = {}

    def displayStudent(self):
        return 'Student Name: ' + self.name + '\n' + 'Student Number: ' + str(self.number)

    def addGrade(self, course, grade):
        self.courses[course] = grade

    def displayGPA(self):
        if len(self.courses) == 0:
            errormsg  = print('oops')
            return errormsg

        else:
            gpa = 0.0
            for course in self.courses.keys():
                gpa = gpa + self.courses[course]
            return 'GPA of student ' + self.name + ' is ' + str(gpa / len(self.courses))


    def displayCourses(self):
        return list(self.courses.keys())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create first student object and add grades for each class
    student1 = Student('John', '013454900')
    student1.addGrade('uli101', 1.0)
    student1.addGrade('ops235', 2.0)
    student1.addGrade('ops435', 3.0)

    # Create second student object and add grades for each class
    student2 = Student('Jessica', '123456')
    student2.addGrade('ipc144', 4.0)
    student2.addGrade('cpp244', 3.5)
    student2.addGrade('cpp344', 0.0)

    # Display information for student1 object
    print(student1.displayStudent())
    print(student1.displayGPA())
    print(student1.displayCourses())

    # Display information for student2 object
    print(student2.displayStudent())
    print(student2.displayGPA())
    print(student2.displayCourses())
```

After executing, it successfully displays this output:

```
Student Name: John
Student Number: 013454900
GPA of student John is 2.0
['ops235', 'ops435', 'uli101']
Student Name: Jessica
Student Number: 123456
GPA of student Jessica is 2.5
['ipc144', 'cpp344', 'cpp244']
```

My problem is, under the `displayCourses(self):` function, I want to display only the courses whose GPA is not `0.0`. Like this...without the course `cpp344`

```
python3 lab6a.py
Student Name: John
Student Number: 013454900
GPA of student John is 2.0
['ops435', 'ops235', 'uli101']
Student Name: Jessica
Student Number: 123456
GPA of student Jessica is 2.5
['cpp244', 'ipc144']
```

Comment: If you understand the code you just posted, you could check the value of each key before returning it in your `displayCourses` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your `displayCourses()` method. Something like

```
return [k for k in self.courses.keys() if self.courses[k] > 0]
```

This checks the value of `self.courses[k]` for each of the courses, and only includes the course in the returned list if the value of that key is greater than zero.